# Is this an alternative to LINQ TO SQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

it bit confusing, i'm reading these articles regarding linq to sql in mvc but are these links are alternative of each other ? mean one is telling to use LINQ to SQL and other something else ?

[Creating Model Classes with LINQ to SQL](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/creating-model-classes-with-linq-to-sql-cs)?

and

[Displaying a Table of Database Data](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/displaying-a-table-of-database-data-cs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one uses [Linq to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Second uses [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx). But it's also mentioned:

> In this tutorial, we use the Microsoft Entity Framework. However, it is important to understand that you can use a variety of different technologies to interact with a database from an ASP.NET MVC application including LINQ to SQL, NHibernate, or ADO.NET.

So, there're variety of technologies you can use. It's up to you and your needs. That's it.

Comment: so you mean that he did same thing with two different technologies just to prove the point

Comment: @James Generally yes.

Answer (score 0):

The second link is using EntityFramework; however, EF is only an ORM. Both examples are using LINQ to SQL.

In the EF example, *MoviesDBEntities* instance is not accurately represented by its reference name, *entities*. The object being instantiated is technically called a *context* (database, in this example). *entities.MovieSet* is an implementation of *IQueryable*, which supports LINQ extensions--specifically *ToList()*, which is the LINQ extension method being used in the EntityFramework example. Calling *ToList()* will cause the *IQueryable* instance to execute a corresponding SQL query, returning an object of type *List<MovieSet>*.